# How to serialize object to json with custom fields in python

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, serialization

I have a class

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,age,name):
        self.person_age = age
        self.person_name = name
```

And i want to serialize object to json. I can do so:

```
person = Person(20,'Piter')
person.__dict__
```

But such an approach will return it:

```
{'person_age':20,person_name:'Piter'}
```

I want serialize my object to json with my own fields. Instead of 'person_age' - 'age'. Instead of 'person_name' - 'name':

```
{'age':20,name:'Piter'}
```

How can this be done if the class has many fields?

Comment: Why are you adding the 'person_' to your fields?

Comment: This is just an example :)

Comment: Use [DRF Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: So you have a mapping of object fields to json fields? Something like `{'person_name' : 'name', 'person_age':'age'}`?

Comment: You could look into jsonpickle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8614096

Comment: @DaniMesejo I just need to implement mapping

Comment: Use a dictionary for the mapping

Comment: @DaniMesejo Then you must use all fields. There may be many. And I only need some

Comment: You only need those you want to change

Comment: @Pikachu - I hope the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307608/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-dto-in-the-service-layer/) worked for you. Do not forget to accept the answer so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you could do the following:

```
import json


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age, name, weight):
        self.person_age = age
        self.person_name = name
        self.weight = weight


p = Person(30, 'Peter', 78)
mapping = {'person_age': 'age', 'person_name': 'name'}
result = json.dumps({mapping.get(k, k): v for k, v in p.__dict__.items()})

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{"age": 30, "name": "Peter", "weight": 78}
```

Note that you only need those names you want to change, in the example above `weight` remains unchanged.

Answer (score -2):

You can use json module to serialize the object to json format.

Here is the example:-

```
import json
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,age,name):
        self.person_age = age
        self.person_name = name

person = Person(20,'Piter')

person_JSON = json.dumps(person.__dict__)
print(person_JSON)
```

Output:-

```
'{"person_age": 20, "person_name": "Piter"}'
```

Comment: He specifically asked to have custom field names when serializing.

Comment: @Daan, nin hendran I have written the code with respect to the question asked. Let me know what exactly is the issue you saw with my code.

Comment: Second part - "I want serialize my object to json with my own fields. Instead of 'person_age' - 'age'. Instead of 'person_name' - 'name':"